90's Sci-fi TV Show about a red-haired teen trying to fit in
I was pretty young and at my dad's friend's house whenever I watched this show. All I can remember is a teen or young girl, with red, chin-length hair. She had a letter on her forehead - I think it was either an X, V or a Y could have been a number maybe. 
I don't remember much other that it was alien and about a family trying to fit in.
I am from England I believe it was either american, Canadian or Australian. Also the whole family were aliens trying to fit in on earth 
They were human like.... but I think they turned into something not so human when they reveal themselves. I believe they had powers too.

Can you please include information about the language or country of origin of this show. Also, it would help if you could explain what you mean by "it was alien". Are the people in the show aliens?

I am from England I believe it was either american, Canadian or Australian. Also the whole family were aliens trying to fit in on earth. They were human like.... but I think they turned into something not so human when they reveal themselves. I believe they had powers too.

Sounds like Halfway Across the Galaxy and Turn Left from 1993. It was about a family of aliens landing on Earth and trying to fit in. Their small daughter was a girl called X with chin-length red hair. They had some special powers and there was a glowing mark on X's forehead when she used hers. The show was based on an Australian novel. There are episodes on Youtube (though they're dubbed in German). Here's the family:


Thank you SO much I think  that was it yeah! It was so hard to remember and fine thank you so much
